# Error en la salida del exe generado.No muestra nada. En VSCode va perfecto el programa

Tags: python-3.x, exe, cx-freeze

primero decir que llevo mas de 10 años sin tocar nada de programación y que ahora que he vuelto a intentar hacer algo ando bastante perdido, asi que perdonad si la respuesta es muy obvia.Gracias.

El problema es que tengo un programa que cuando lo ejecuto en el VSCode pues me va bien,veo en el terminal la ejecucion de este, pero cuando lo convierto a exe no hay manera de ver el resultado.

Trabajo con Entorno virtual generado con Pipenv,python 3.9, Windows 10 y VSCode o Atom.

el programa es el siguiente :

```
from time import sleep
import sys
from playsound import playsound
import pyttsx3

def voz():
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    engine.setProperty("rate", 5)
    engine.say("ai ")
    engine.setProperty("rate", 125)
    engine.say("Vaya parece que ya me he despertado")
    engine.say("Quien eres tu?")
    engine.runAndWait()
    engine.stop()


def inicio():
    texto = "Hola enano"
    playsound('ejemplo.wav', 0)

    for x in texto:
        print(x, end="")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sleep(0.2)


inicio()
input()
```

Lo que hace es escribir Hola enano letra a letra con el wav de fondo.
Utilizo un entorno virtual con pipenv donde tengo instalados los modulos necesarios y el exe lo genero con cx_freeze.
He intentado generar el exe con diferentes configuraciones en el setup.py pero nada.
Este es mi ultimo archivo setup.py

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["sys", "time", "playsound", "pyttsx3"]}

"""base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"
"""
    
executables = [Executable("mylittleworld.py", base=None)]
options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options}
   
setup(
      name="mylittleworld",
      version="0.1",
      description="simulacion",
      options =options,
      executables=executables,
)
```

El base lo he dejado al final en "None" porque sino no puedo ver el error por consola.He incluido los modulos aunque no es necesario en principio.

Esta es la salida del exe, pero no tengo claro cual es el error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\David\.virtualenvs\MylittleWorld-9q2P1u6Y\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 41, in run
    module.run()
  File "C:\Users\David\.virtualenvs\MylittleWorld-9q2P1u6Y\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 36, in run
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "mylittleworld.py", line 28, in <module>
  File "mylittleworld.py", line 20, in inicio
  File "C:\Users\David\.virtualenvs\MylittleWorld-9q2P1u6Y\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 35, in _playsoundWin
    winCommand('open "' + sound + '" alias', alias)
  File "C:\Users\David\.virtualenvs\MylittleWorld-9q2P1u6Y\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 30, in winCommand
    '\n    ' + errorBuffer.value.decode())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfa in position 49: invalid start byte
```

Espero que alguien puede echarme una mano.
Si necesitáis mas información decirmelo porfavor.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, la verdad es que se me pasó por la cabeza lo de las rutas, incluso iba a quitar lo del playsound pero al funcionar en el VSCode ya no le di más importancia, en cuanto pueda lo pruebo con la ruta completa a ver qué hace y también voy a quitar lo del sonido a ver. Gracias de nuevo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Investigando el mensaje de error

Cuando se produce una excepción Python vuelca el llamado *stacktrace* que debe leerse comenzando por el final. Allí encontramos:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfa in position 49: invalid start byte
```

Este es el error que causó la excepción. Se trata de un problema al tratar de leer una cadena. La cadena se intenta leer como utf8, pero contiene un carácter de valor `0xfa` que no es válido en utf8. Típicamente esto ocurre cuando la cadena no está en realidad en utf-8 sino en otro *encoding*. No obstante ¿quién estaba intentado leer esa cadena? ¿de dónde viene?

Para saber la verdadera causa conviene continuar leyendo la traza, de abajo arriba, ya que la línea anterior nos dirá qué estaba haciendo el código cuando se produjo esa excepción, y la anterior a esa desde qué instrucción se había llamado a ese código, y la anterior indica desde qué instrucción se había llamado a la función anterior y así sucesivamente, hasta que arriba del todo suele estar la instrucción de nuestro código (o del *framework* en el que nuestro código esté incluido) que desencadenó todo esto.

De modo que si leemos de abajo arriba el *stacktrace* vemos que el error se produjo cuando en algún momento se intentó:

```
    '\n    ' + errorBuffer.value.decode())
```

Es decir, la cadena en cuestión era algún tipo de mensaje de error. Esto fue causado por la llamada a:

```
   winCommand('open "' + sound + '" alias', alias)
```

línea que forma parte de `playsound.py`

### Hipótesis

Tenemos ya suficientes elementos para intentar deducir qué ocurrió. Al intentar el comando `playsound('ejemplo.wav', 0)` la biblioteca utiliza `winCommand()` para ejecutar un comando windows (el comando `open ejemplo.wav`, aparentemente), y ese comando falla. El mensaje de error devuelto por windows contiene el carácter 0xfa que posteriormente causa la excepción que vimos.

La razón por la que ese comando esté fallando puede ser que no se encuentra el fichero "ejemplo.wav".

En windows la codificación del sistema depende del país, pero en español lo normal es que sea CP1252 en vez de UTF-8. En CP1252 el carácter '0xfa` es perfectamente válido y representa la "ú".

De hecho esto es un indicio a favor de la hipótesis, ya que ante un fichero no encontrado el mensaje de error de Windows es:

> *"Windows no puede encontrar el archivo "ejemplo.wav". Asegúrese de que el nombre esté escrito correctamente e inténtelo de nuevo"*

y en este mensaje el primer carácter no-ascii que aparece es precisamente una `ú` (de "Asegúrese")

### Solución

Si el mensaje de error se debe a que el fichero no ha sido encontrado, es que no se está buscando en la carpeta del script. Esto explica por qué funcionaría en VSCode (porque en ese caso sí se busca en la carpeta desde donde fue lanzado) pero no funciona al empaquetarlo en un exe (porque en ese caso la carpeta desde la que se ejecuta el script no coincide necesariamente con la carpeta que contiene el recurso .wav)

La solución sería entonces especificar la ruta absoluta al archivo.

De todas formas, para que el programa pueda ser ejecutado en otras máquinas, el archivo "ejemplo.wav" debería formar parte del instalable. Esto se puede configurar en cx_Freeze, pero entonces acceder al archivo desde el script python no es tan simple ya que ni siquiera conoceremos la ruta absoluta del recurso (pues depende de dónde lo haya instalado el usuario final).

Por suerte cx_Freeze tiene forma de averiguar las rutas de los recursos incluidos de este modo. Esta es una receta sacada de su [F.A.Q](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#using-data-files):

```
def find_data_file(filename):
    if getattr(sys, "frozen", False):
        # The application is frozen
        datadir = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
    else:
        # The application is not frozen
        # Change this bit to match where you store your data files:
        datadir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    return os.path.join(datadir, filename)
```

Comment: Una explicación muy profesional, espero que también le pueda servir de ayuda a otros.Muchas Gracias por la explicación y por tu tiempo. Un saludo.